# How to set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in VSTS/TFS releases?

Tags: tfs, deployment, azure-devops

How to set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable in VSO deploy template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is just an environment variable, and the Variables in the TFS Scripted build/releases are set as environment variables.

You can set the from either the Variables tab in Build / Release when editing a definition:

[image]

or per Environment in a Release:

[image]